# Segmentation fault in scanf

Tags: c

While running this code, I encounter Segmentation fault at scanf(). This is possibly due to the declaration of large arrays(I checked it by commenting the arrays declaration).

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int test;
    //int n,ok,counter,i,j;
    char a[1000][1000];
    int x[1000][1000],y[1000][1000];
    scanf("%d",&test);
    printf("%d",test);
    return 0;
}
```

Since, I need those arrays, can someone suggest me how correctify this code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are defining some huge objects locally. Local variables are created on the stack and the stack has limits (per thread). Sometimes the stack can be a maximum of 1 megabyte. Your arrays would be well beyond that. My guess is you are actually overflowing the stack. You could move the array definitions outside of main and your program should work as those arrays wouldn't be created on the stack. You could also define your arrays by making them `static` in `main`. This has the same effect as declaring them outside.

Globally defined variables (including uninitialized arrays) and `static` uninitialized variables (even if they are in a function) generally get placed in a data segment and initialized when your program is run. They are also guaranteed to be set to all 0. This [Wiki reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss) describes this data area in C as:

> BSS in C
>
> In C, statically-allocated objects without an explicit initializer are initialized to zero (for arithmetic types) or a null pointer (for pointer types). Implementations of C typically represent zero values and null pointer values using a bit pattern consisting solely of zero-valued bits (though this is not required by the C standard). Hence, the BSS section typically includes all uninitialized variables declared at file scope (i.e., outside of any function) as well as uninitialized local variables declared with the static keyword. An implementation may also assign statically-allocated variables initialized with a value consisting solely of zero-valued bits to the bss section.

The `BSS` segment is not constrained like the stack is. `BSS` could use up to available memory if the resources exist and you don't exceed any process quotas.

Another alternative is to dynamically allocate the arrays using `malloc` which would put them on the heap. The following code would be the easiest way to create your arrays. I used `#define` to make it clearer what is a row and column. After these arrays are defined and memory allocated they can be used like any normal 2D array.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    #define ROWS 1000
    #define COLUMNS 1000
    int test;

    char (*a)[COLUMNS] = malloc(ROWS * sizeof *a);
    int  (*x)[COLUMNS] = malloc(ROWS * sizeof *x);
    int  (*y)[COLUMNS] = malloc(ROWS * sizeof *y);

    a[100][20] = 'X';
    x[4][999] = 666;
    y[500][0] =  42;

    scanf("%d",&test);
    printf("%d",test);

    free(a);
    free(x);
    free(y);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I declared the arrays outside main and now it is working fine. But, for the knowledge purpose, can you tell me how it differs when we put it inside our main?

Comment: I've provided some sample code to do the array definition and initialization with `malloc`

Comment: Note: Rather than `ROWS * COLUMNS * sizeof(char)`, `ROWS * COLUMNS * sizeof(int)`, consider `ROWS * sizeof *a` and `ROWS * sizeof *b`.

Comment: Thanks I had created the answer rather fast and didn't think of adding that transformation at the time. No need to specify the types twice.

Answer (score 1):

You are allocating huge memory on stack and that is causing [**stackoverflow!**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow#Very_large_stack_variables)  You should use `malloc()` for such cases, it will allocate the memory on heap. Also you need to `free()`the memory after usage.

This is a sample code you can use, I have only done it for `a` variable you can use similar code for your `x` and `y` variable:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char **a; 
    int i, j;
    a = malloc(1000*sizeof(char*));
    for(i=0;i<1000;i++)
    {
        a[i] = malloc(1000*sizeof(char));
        for(j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
        {
            //Your operations
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i< 1000; i++)
        free( a[i]);
    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```