# Getting an overflow when creating an integer array?

Tags: c, arrays

I am getting an overflow for using this.
int x[471][640];
Someone told me to use Malloc? I have no idea what that is. Its not in my book nor my lectures. Any fix to this?

Comment: Search for it. You're trying to allocate ~1.1MB on the stack (which is too much).  Dynamic allocation is a very basic C concept, it will be covered by any tutorial.

Comment: Type "malloc tutorial" into Google and take it from there.

Comment: here you go
http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/malloc/

Comment: I recently [wrote a response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26077874/segmentation-fault-in-scanf/26077933#26077933) to another Stackoverflow question regarding large arrays (on the stack) and options to deal with them. Although the questions are different I believe the end result is from the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not know yet about C function malloc then you can try another approach. For example declare your local array as

```
static int x[471][640];
```

that is as having static storage duration.

If you also do not know yet about the keyword static then the only approach I can suggest is to declare the array globally that is outside any function. for example before main:)