# When I want for define to set 1000000, program in process crashed

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

When I want to `#define` for `SIZE` 1.000.000 , my program crashed before it start main function, but when i `#define` for `SIZE` 100.000 it work. I have two arrays initialization in my program.

```
#define SIZE 1000000
char *baza_vocka[SIZE];    
    char b_vocka[SIZE];
```

**EDIT**: They are local variables.

Comment: I am curious. Do you define `char *baza_vocka[SIZE];` inside a function (`main` or any other function) or are they declared outside a function at global scope?

Comment: That observation is a bit soft. I can't imagine this would cause a problem in global scope.

Comment: What does "crash" mean?

Comment: You are experimenting some *stack overflow*, ....

Comment: With the edit that these are local variables you are encountering a stack overflow because the arrays are too big to fit on the stack. I wrote an answer to another *related* post with some extra information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26077874/segmentation-fault-in-scanf

Answer (score 3):

In case of 1M you're trying to allocate an array on the stack, which is bigger than the stack size. For such sizes you need to allocate the memory on heap.

For example:

```
int main()
{
    // allocation on the heap
    char **baza_vocka = malloc(sizeof(char*)*SIZE);
    char *b_vocka = malloc(sizeof(char)*SIZE);

    // working code
    baza_vocka[1] = 0x0;
    b_vocka[1] = 'a';

    // cleaning the heap
    free(b_vocka);
    free(baza_vocka);
}
```

Comment: No, a 1M `static` array is ok.  But a local array is not ok.

Comment: Agreed, I just compiled and ran a program with a static array `char * ptr [4000000];`

Comment: Whether it works or not will also depend on your compiler settings and what the stack size is and the total size of the array structure.

Comment: But the example is with a heap-allocated array... And is C++, not C!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I think he meant a stack allocated array. Static arrays are defined in a special exe section and they don't need to be allocated.

Comment: @Eldar: I know that, but the answer still mentions "static array"

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Sorry, I thought you were OP

Comment: My comment about whether it works or not was actually addressing the `No, a 1M static array is ok. But a local array is not ok` . It may be okay or it may not. But I think the point we are both making is that big objects on the stack are a bad idea because you will *run the risk* of an overflow

Comment: In C, don't cast the result of malloc.

Comment: @Étienne Oh, yeah. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks for responding, but i have two question, 1. what is 1M , 2. what have been minding with (**) , what is that , (char **baza_vocka)?

Comment: 1. 1M = 1'000'000 = one million, that was defined in SIZE macro and stated in the question,
2. (char **) is converting (void *) to pointer to pointer to char. If you like the answer, please mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that `baza_vocka` is a *local* variable, perhaps inside `main`

You are experimenting some [*stack overflow*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow), .... Local call frames  should usually be small (a few kilobytes) in your [call stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack)

You should not have so big local variables. Allocate such big arrays in the heap using `malloc` or `calloc`. Don't forget to test that they are not failing. Read documentation of [malloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html), and don't forget to `free` such a heap allocated array. Beware of [memory leaks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) & [buffer overflows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow). Use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) if available.

On current desktops, stack space is a few megabytes, so you usually should limit each call frame to a few kilobytes (or a few dozens of kilobytes).